# Weird results of exponential when exiting queue on timeout

Tags: queue, timeout, anylogic, exponential

I'm quite a beginner in Anylogic, so maybe my question is moronic.

What I'm trying to do is to create a model of M/M/1 with reneging, i.e. an agent waits in queue for a (random) amount of time and then exits the queue via timeOut.

Also, I've inserted timeMeasureStart and timeMeasureEnd in order to find the mean time spent in queue for the agents which left the queue by timeOut: [MM1 with reneging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCtWX.png).

I've tried to set constant time, uniform, triangular and normal random time - the mean time (and the deviation) was as the theory predicts.

But when I tried to use exponential (and weibull), the mean time was significantly less then the mean value of the distribution.

I wonder if someone could explain to me why it happens?

Comment: The mean of exponential distribution is 1/lambda, not lambda itself. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: No, that's not it. But I think I figured it out. It's possible that the simulation time was not long enough. Since the exponential distribution tends to produce small random numbers with a higher probability, I believe the mean time would eventually increase. Sadly, my Anylogic PLE has a 50000 agents limit. The last result I observed indicates the mean time is increasing with longer simulation time.